# Plone5 view permission depending on permission of folder

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I'm trying to deploy an "intranet" folder hierarchie with a simple workflow, that:

- shut of anonymous users from that hierarchie, even sub-levels
- let users of a certain group enter that hierarchie only, even sub-levels
- have private objects unvisible by default
- upon publishing make them visble to all users of the group
- private folders should deny other users (except admins) to enter that folder and access any object below

This scenario is discussed here: http://blog.keul.it/2011/10/plone-security-and-workflows-learn-how.html?m=1

It's more or less the same here: [Plone Intranet workflow and group permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790912/plone-intranet-workflow-and-group-permissions)

The answer of the question of above is:

> 1. Leave the page or folder in the private workflow state, NOT published internally. (I think this is the step you were missing.) 2.
>      On the Sharing tab for the page or folder, grant 'Can view' to the
>      group you want to share with, just like you already tried. You don't
>      have to change the "inherit permissions from higher levels" checkbox.

However, if I grant 'can view' only, the user may not enter the folder, but if I grant 'can add', too, the user may enter. However, this makes all objects below visible to all users of that group.

Example:

user is member of group1
folder in private state
-> share with group1 'can view'

user may not enter folder;

-> share with group1 'can add'
user may enter and sees all object, even private ones

This is Plone 5.0.6, should this setup work?

Comment: It's not easy to answer this. You must share your workflow configuration.
Which workflow are you using for folders and other contents?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reminder in general, though it might not answer the question per se.
1) Make sure you configure the 'real' target on its Sharing tab. For example, a folder with a default view might mislead the target. 2) Likewise, items with `index_html` IDs in a folder will become the default view, that might mislead the target. 3) **Can View** in the Sharing tab means **Reader** role in the workflow settings. Check permission settings in Workflow State. The following is my example settings hopefully gives hints.

[image: Workflow State permission]